# stdoutLog is not created

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, logging

We deployed our .net core application, and it is not working. I tried to debug by enabling stdoutLog in web.config:

```
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\myApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myAppQA\logs">
```

I also created the logs folder. I used the absolute path after trying relative path, too.

The log file was created 2 times only, and very inconsistently, and finally stopped being created at all. How can I make logging work?

Comment: Where is it deployed? On Azure App Services the path is `D:/home/site/wwwroot`.

Comment: @Dai It is deployed on Azure VM's IIS. I cannot put a file name, as it should be generated, e.g. stdout_5028_201962617345.log

Comment: That log file is only created if ASP.NET Core module is successfully initialized. So in your case, describe clearly what error page is. If the error page comes from ASP.NET Core module, there can be no log.

Comment: @Lex Li In Startup's Configure() there is app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");Other than that I am not sure what I can tell.

Comment: No error is reported in EventViewer, and the error is 500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.